# C++ Memory leaks on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, memory-leaks, mingw

I'm writing a program (C++, MinGW 32 bit) to batch process images using OpenCV functions, using AngelScript as a scripting language. As of right now, my software has some memory leaks that add up pretty quickly (the images are 100-200 MB each, and I'm processing thousands at once) but I'm running into an image where Windows doesn't seem to be releasing the memory used by my program until rebooting.

If I run it on a large set of images, it runs for a while and eventually OpenCV throws an exception saying that it's out of memory. At that point, I close the program, and Task Manager's physical memory meter drops back down to where it was before I started. But here's the catch - every time I try to run the program again, it will fail right off the bat to allocate memory to OpenCV, until I reboot the computer, at which point it will work just great for a few hundred images again.

Is there some way Windows could be holding on to that memory? Or is there another reason why Windows would fail to allocate memory to my program until a reboot occurs? This doesn't make sense to me.

**EDIT:** The computer I'm running this program on is Windows 7 64 bit with 32 GB of ram, so even with my program's memory issues, it's only using a small amount of the available memory. Normally the program maxes out at a little over 1 GB of ram before it quits.

**EDIT 2:** I'm also using FreeImage to load the images, I forgot to mention that. Here's the basis of my processing code:

```
//load bitmap with FreeImage
FIBITMAP *bitmap = NULL;
FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;
fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename.c_str(), 0);
bitmap = FreeImage_Load(fif, filename.c_str(), 0);
if (!bitmap) {
    LogString("ScriptEngine: input file is not readable.");
    processingFile = false;
    return false;
}
//convert FreeImage bitmap to my custom wrapper for OpenCV::Mat
ScriptImage img;
img.image = fi2cv(bitmap);
FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);

try {
    //this executes the AngelScript code
    r = ctx->Execute();
} catch(std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "Exception in " << __FILE__ << ", line " << __LINE__ << ", " << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
}

try {
    engine->GarbageCollect(asGC_FULL_CYCLE | asGC_DESTROY_GARBAGE);
} catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "Exception in " << __FILE__ << ", line " << __LINE__ << ", " << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, the only pointer is to the FIBITMAP, which is freed.

Comment: wait, ***one*** image is 100 mb??

Comment: Yes, the images are high-resolution uncompressed TIFFs.

Comment: can you provide a minimal code, or at least the portion which throws the exception? How are you reading and releasing the image buffers?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a memory leak or that you simply dont have enough memory? A memory leak only exists if you have allocated memory but dont hold any references to it anymore. This means that this is not a leak: `vector<double> vec; for(int i = 0; i < 10000000000000000000000; i++) { vec.push_back(i); }` though this code will probably consume all your memory.

Comment: Looks like OpenCV does its work on the GPU, so I'm guessing it isn't Windows per se that's responsible for memory allocation.  I don't know how OpenCL memory allocation works, it may be normal that it isn't automatically released when the process exits.  That might also explain why you're maxing out at 1GB, I'm guessing your video card only has 1GB RAM.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I compiled OpenCV myself and I'm not using the GPU module, so AFAIK all processing is done using the CPU.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, unless you *explicitly* copy images to cv::ocl::Mat or such, processing is done on the cpu in opencv

Comment: You're sure a subprocess isn't being created?  There shouldn't be any way for a process to cause memory to be lost to the kernel without device driver involvement.  What error code do you receive on the second run, and what API is returning it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I'm doing some threading, but I'm not creating any subprocesses as far as I know. OpenCV is what ends up returning the error, saying that it can't allocate memory. Could dynamic linkage have something to do with that? All of the libraries I'm using are linked as DLLs.

Comment: No, dynamic linkage doesn't affect the way memory is managed.  I can only assume that either OpenCV is doing something odd (such as allocating the memory on the GPU or within a separate process) or there's something wrong with your machine - do you have access to another machine you could test your code on?  For example, anti-virus software could theoretically mess up memory management, though I've never heard of it happening.

Comment: Since you're compiling OpenCV yourself, perhaps you could try building your code and OpenCV together, so that you can step into OpenCV to see where the underlying failure is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you are making a copy of the image data on this line:

```
img.image = fi2cv(bitmap);
```

Since you are immediately freeing the bitmap afterwards, that data must persist after the free.

Check if there is a resource release for ScriptImage objects.

Comment: That function only uses cv::Mat objects, and does not allocate any memory, so it shouldn't be a problem. However, my question isn't why memory is leaking (I know that it is) but why the behavior caused by my program running out of memory seems to persist until I reboot Windows.

Comment: There is likely a runtime element to the library you're using. You might be able to see it and end the task using windows task explorer or SysInternals Process Explorer.

Comment: What do you mean by "runtime element"? If you mean that one of the libraries is starting another process, I don't think that that's very likely.

Comment: There has to be something else running. Windows isolates memory to windows processes. If you have a memory leak that persists *after* your program has exited then there is another process in the system holding that memory. 

Get a copy of [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and use it too examine everything running in your system. It has a tab for private bytes or memory in use for every process (and thread) running on your computer. (This tool shows much more than windows task manager will.)

Comment: That's not *quite* true; the memory could be being held by a kernel-mode component, such as a GPU driver or anti-virus software, or OpenCV might be misreporting the actual cause of the problem and there isn't really any memory missing.  It pretty much has to be one of these three possibilities, but which one is anybody's guess. :-)

Comment: That's a fair point. If there is a kernel object that holds the memory you are in trouble. In general those are bad kernel components.